# How to define attr value for Theme dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, android-theme, android-styles

Let me clarify the question.
I have theme like this

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/DefaultTextViewStyle</item>        
</style>
```

where

```
<style name="DefaultTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attrTextColor</item>
</style>
```

for application I use the DefaultTheme theme, and I want to change value of the attrTextColor dynamically from code (to change text color for all TextView). Can I do it? How Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

For simple explication, you can do it with theme.

You have to define your attributes

```
<attr name="color_menu" format="color"/>
<attr name="color_text_main" format="color"/>
```

Define your theme color (here, blue and green)

```
<style name="AppTheme_green" parent="DefaultTheme">
  <item name="color_menu">@color/very_dark_green</item>
  <item name="color_text_main">@color/very_dark_gray3</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme_blue" parent="DefaultTheme">
  <item name="color_menu">@color/very_dark_blue</item>
  <item name="color_text_main">@color/very_dark_gray1</item>
</style>
```

Now your current activity can have juste one theme in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_green"
 >
 ...
 </activity>
```

But you can change it dynamically in your activity

```
activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Blue);
```

I hope this can help you